# Radial Gradient and absolute positioning producing different results in different browsers

Tags: css, layout, gradient, radial-gradients

I have developed a switch board with two electronic switches and two lights, it is producing different results in different browsers.

## Chrome Output

In Chrome it is working good.

[Click for Larger Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/st2U5.png)

[image]

## Safari Output

The shiny labels of buttons are pushed to bottom

[Click for Larger Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4Ye7.png)

[image]

## Fire Fox Output

The radial gradient is DULL

[Click for Larger Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YVvb.png)

[image]

Is there any thing i am missing while doing cross browser platform support?

Any suggestions please! Any help will be highly appreciated

Please look for Present version [**Code Pen Link**](http://codepen.io/Sud_/pen/tjAJB) **It is with comments**

Comment: +1 I love those switches.

Comment: The labels of buttons are pushed to the bottom in Chrome as well, maybe because I am using a Mac.

Comment: @Antony: Thanks for your response. Oh , i am testing on windows :( , you have added some more problems :) :) ...

Comment: I thought `reset.css` would help but it didn't. If you wouldn't mind using some ugly workaround, here is the result of a browser-specific hack for the labels using `-webkit-margin-start`: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ccsbq

Comment: @Antony: Great, by the way what you have done to fix this?

Comment: I used `-webkit-margin-before: 70%;` to override `margin: 90% 32% 8%;` in `.on.switch:before`, and `-webkit-margin-before: 77%;` to override `margin-top: 97%;` in `.switch:before`. This is not an elegant solution, but it is a quick fix for Safari and Chrome.

Comment: That's because `-webkit` prefixes affects both Safari and Chrome. Let me see if there are some other solutions.

Comment: @Antony:My major target are safari and chrome, as ie is ruled out for gradients, but i think there are some os differences in rendering of output among browsers, because chrome output in windows is different, but thanks for your efforts so far :) , why don't you post this as an answer :)

Comment: Because this is a hack, not really a solution. I would post it as an answer when I find the real fix.

Comment: @Antony: Resets are generic old stuff; they won't do anything about gradients. They're not a magic pill that can solve every single browser inconsistency.

Comment: @BoltClock I was trying to use resets to fix margin inconsistencies. But yeah, they are no magic pills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed label position and gradient : [Code Pen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JbACK)

To fix the position of the labels, use `top` instead of `margin-top`.

```css
.switch:before { /* Used for Inner Ligths of switch */
  content: "";/* Without this no layout positioning will work */
  background: rgb(53, 244, 252);/* Sandy white color */
  width: 36%;/* occupied 36% of switch (which is 50% of board frame */
  position: absolute;
  height: 4px;/* Light height */
  margin-top: 0%;/* 36% width + 32 % left border + 32% right border = 100% of switch width */
  top: 77%;
  margin-left: 32% ;
  margin-right: 32% ;
  marging-bottom :0px;
  border-radius: 12px;/* Light radius */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);/* Switch light shadow */
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);/* Switch Light border */
}

.on.switch:before {/* Used to target light of switch */
  margin: 0% 32% 8%; /* Move light of switch up so it appears that light is actually on */
  top: 70%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.42);
}
```

The problem is not in Safari or Chrome, but rather Firefox doesn't handle `margin-top` in percentage properly. I tried setting `margin-top: 100%` and only Safari and Chrome (Mac version) render the label below the switch. Firefox determines that 100% is less than the full height of the switch.

As for the gradient in Firefox, simply move the line `radial-gradient` to the top and leave `-moz-radial-gradient` at the bottom. This would allow the browser specific CSS to take effect.

```css
.radial:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:-240px;
  /* width: 1200px;*/
  /*max-width: 100%;*/
  width:100%;
  height: 920px;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 2%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 56%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,0.75) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.65) 2%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 56%,rgba(255,255,255,0.05  ) 60%,rgba(255,255,255,0.04) 70%,rgba(255,255,255,0.04) 80%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,0.75) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.65) 2%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 56%,rgba(255,255,255,0.05   ) 60%,rgba(255,255,255,0.04) 70%,rgba(255,255,255,0.04) 80%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,0.75) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.65) 2%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 56%,rgba(255,255,255,0.05 ) 60%,rgba(255,255,255,0.04) 70%,rgba(255,255,255,0.04) 80%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
  z-index: -21;
}
```

Comment: Well, what can i say :) .. Thanks a ton .. i am very happy to see this problem solved :) and thanks to stack overflow :)